# Handling data that may or may not be a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Is there a way to determine if an arbitrary js object is an angular promise?  I would like to have different behavior based on whether the result of a function is a promise.  I can check to see if the object has a 'then' function, but is there a better way?

Comment: You could just wrap your regular function in a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for `.then()` sounds reasonable to me, but you may be looking for $q's `when()`. This will let you handle everything as though it were a promise so you can normalize the behavior of promise and non promise data.

Here's an example using jQuery's promise api (it's almost identical and easier to setup): **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/EWoreXaj/1/edit)**

```
var deferred = new $.Deferred();
deferred.resolve('some promise data.');
var promise = deferred.promise();

x = 'some regular data.';

foo(x);
foo(promise);

function foo(input) {
  $.when(input).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: That's perfect!  Thanks. I hadn't learned about `when()` yet.